# problem adding complex objects to database from angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to add a group Id to the database but my data model has type "Group" how can I achieve adding a GroupId without sending the whole object

Here is my Data model class

```
public class Tool : IObjectBase
    {
        public Group Group { get; set; } // My problem is here 

        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Statut { get; set; }
        public string StorageLocation { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CalibrationDate { get; set; }
        public string InventoryNumber { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string StandardLoanPeriod { get; set; }
```

using Entity Framework core I was able to add this class as a table to the database and of course ef will make that group object as an GroupId in the table

So now in my angular application, I am trying to add a new Tool to the database using this Method

```
AddNewTool(form: NgForm) {
    this.tool = {
      Id :  form.value.Id,
      Code: form.value.Code,
      Name: form.value.Name,
      Description: form.value.Description,
      Image: '',
      Group: this.Group // Probleme is here 
    };
    this.service.AddTool(this.tool).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.ToolToReload.emit(this.service.getTools());
        this.toolRowInformation = null;
        console.log(res);
        form.resetForm();
      } ,
      err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Now, whenever I add a new tool it works and the groupId get filled with that group but at the same time, that group added to the group table in the database.

I tried sending only the GroupId from angular but I get an error telling that the Tool is Expecting a Group object not a string.

My question is is it possible to add a tool with a groupId without sending the whole Group Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `GroupId` property in your data model class as well as the group object.
This way, you can send the `GroupId` to and from the client and also access the `Group` navigation property in your data model class:

```cs
public int GroupId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response i already tried that but whenever i add a new tool it asks me to send a group object as well